# Eclipse RCP: How and when to correctly unsubscribe a Composite from EventBroker?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

In the constructor of my custom composite (inherited from SWT `Composite`), I register myself as an EventHandler to the Eclipse `IEventBroker`.

To unsubscribe upon disposal, I had overridden the `dispose` method where I unsubscribe myself.

But I now noticed that this unsubscription is not happening, indeed the `dispose` method is never getting called.

What is the correct way to unsubscribe myself, or to avoid that a closed Composite/ViewPart leaves "leaking" event handlers behind?

I use Eclipse RCP 3.x (so no annotations/injection). In E4 I could use the automatic Event subscription or the @Predestroy method, if I understood it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `addDisposeListener` of the `Composite` to add a `DisposeListener` and do the unsubscribe in the listener.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be correct to call `addDisposeListener` from the constructor of my `Composite`, just after subscribing to the `EventBroker`?

Comment: Another question: is using the DisposeListener the "canonical" way to handle the disposing? I.e. I never have to override the dispose method?

Comment: Yes. The dispose method is only used to start of the dispose process and is never called for children of the top level control being disposed (an internal `release` method is called instead).

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the help. I just also found this very old [article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm) which seems to say the same thing.